# How to determine Oracle client version

Tags: oracle, delphi

I use Direct Oracle Access components. Is there a way to determine which version of Oracle client is being used to access a database?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking how to use the Direct Oracle Access components to do it or are you open to using alternate methods to find the client version?

Comment: It doesn't matter :)
But I'd prefer to use DOA, if it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used DOA before. But the oci.dll file has a function called OCIClientVersion that you could call. You could also use the Windows API GetFileVersionInfo() on the oci.dll file to get the major and minor version, if that's all you are looking for.